# Anyone working on updating the broken links related to C++ FAQ?

Tags: discussion, editing-help, external-links

C++ FAQ has moved from http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ to https://isocpp.org/faq. All links going to former are getting redirected to later. In some cases. those links are going to topic section header rather than to exact FAQ. Look at http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.8 for example. https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness is the new link for all FAQs for previous section 18. This will make many questions irrelevant. I can mark few of these, but with low reputation, I cannot do much. What are the options?

**Update 1:**

Could it be possible that we can get in touch with nice people at ISOCPP & Parashift and ask them to publish old FAQ to new FAQ mapping on github or somewhere on ISOCPP itself for reference. If they do not do it, we will have to start a github repository where we can post the mapping like below

1. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html
   redirects to https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance
2. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html#faq-25.9
   redirects to
   https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#virtual-inheritance-where
3. http://parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html#faq-25.10
   redirects to
   https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#mi-delegate-to-sister

It will be easier for people to start editing the questions then. What will happen otherwise is that links pointing to parashift in 2 & 3 above will get reassigned to ISOCPP link mentioned in 1 and that will be additional work for the reader.

**Update 2:**

I posted the query at official ISOCPP "C++ FAQ discussion" google group [here](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/faq-discussion/B8Gp4NenD9k). Marshall Cline responded back as follows

> While I fix the script, I reverted the parashift.com site. I will
>   repost the (corrected) proxy-pages in a day or three.

As pointed out below by @5gon12eder though, the best solution would be for SE team to do it through some scripts en masse.

Comment: Suggest edits. Rally the community, nuke all broken links with fire.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker... I have low reputations being not able to answer many things hence not able to edit many a times. I was thinking that would not be better for website admins to flag this in the community and see if some people with better reputations can do that or perhaps an automated solution could be devised..

Comment: @GeorgeStocker hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1035806/368070) was a good enough correction. The answer is mostly rendered useless if the new link is placed because all the answer does is references/mentions text from the old faq.

Comment: Id use archive.org links.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The deed is done! [I've updated parashift](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286852/1392132).

Comment: Well done! I'd appreciate to see you participating actively at the SO [tag:c++] questions coming in as well!

Comment: Great! Is the `parashift.com` site to stay online in this version or should we still edit the links?

Comment: Could the page created by @5gon12eder with mapping from old to new be posted at ISOCPP site?

Comment: @user2876962 I don't know how I would go about doing so.  I am not able to edit anything in their wiki.  Maybe somebody else can do it if deemed useful.  I certainly don't have any objections.

Comment: Re "Is the parashift.com site to stay online in this version or should we still edit the links?": no prob, I will keep parashift.com up.

Comment: @MarshallCline is the site parashift.com now completely shout down and moved to isocpp.com FAQ section.

Answer (score 21):

This isn't something that can easily be done at once, it will require getting a lot of people together to make the switch. So start rallying the community to help, whether you can directly edit posts or only [suggest edits](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing).

You can use the `url:` filter on search results to get answers pointing to specific pages.

There appear to be [2786 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Aparashift.com%2Fc%2B%2B-faq) that point to the C++ FAQ pages.

- [147 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Aparashift.com%2Fc%2B%2B-faq*%2Fconst-correctness) point to the ["Const correctness" page](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness)
- [328 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Aparashift.com%2Fc%2B%2B-faq*%2Fctors) point to the ["Constructors" page](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors)
- [200 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Aparashift.com%2Fc%2B%2B-faq*%2Ftemplates) point to the ["Templates" page](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates)
- [56 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Aparashift.com%2Fc%2B%2B-faq*%2Fmultiple-inheritance) point to the ["Multiple inheritance" page](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance)
- [89 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Aparashift.com%2Fc%2B%2B-faq*%2Ffreestore-mgmt) point to the ["Memory management" page](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt)
- [81 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Aparashift.com%2Fc%2B%2B-faq*%2Freferences) point to the ["References" page](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references)

*Feel free to update this answer with lists pointing to the other pages, so others can easily filter down their searches when correcting links.*

Comment: There are actually 2,786 if you count the ones that point to http://parashift.com/c++-faq/ as well. ([search link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Aparashift.com%2Fc%2B%2B-faq))

Comment: As there are a bunch of pages in the C++ FAQ, all with their own links, I've only included a few for now. Feel free to update this answer with links to the other pages though, it will make it easier for people to quickly find answers that need to be updated.

Comment: Don't forget to include the link to [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286672/anyone-working-on-updating-the-broken-links-related-to-c-faq?cb=1) conversation in comment of suggested edit or your suggestion can be rejected by reviewers.

Comment: Not so sure editing all those posts is a great idea. Some diligent people went ahead to edit away without having 2k rep, so they are flooding the edit review queue. I accepted every such edit, but still it seems a bit unnecessary. Better if 2k+ rep users do the editing. And those with enough rep to do edit reviews, please come help with the suggested edits queue...

Comment: Could it be possible that we can get in touch with nice people at ISOCPP and Parashift and ask them to publish old FAQ to new FAQ mapping on a github or somewhere on ISOCPP itself for reference. If they do not do it, we will have to start a github repository where we can post the mapping like below

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html#faq-25.10 maps to https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#mi-delegate-to-sister

It will be easier for people to start editing the questions then.

Comment: Do we really want to spend our time manually editing one of these links after the other?  It might be worthwhile for well received questions but for the bulk I would prefer a (semi-)automated solution.  Once we have a suitable mapping of URLs, it shouldn't be too hard to write a little script using the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/).  The above list is a good starting point for this.  However, I must admit I have never used the API myself and I'm not even sure whether such use is encouraged or even permitted.

Answer (score 17):

> Could it be possible that we can get in touch with nice people at ISOCPP & Parashift and ask them to publish old FAQ to new FAQ mapping on github or somewhere on ISOCPP itself for reference.

Let's go for it!  What is the worst that can happen?  I have just written the following mail to Marshall Cline, editor of the C++ FAQ.  I'll post an update as soon as I get an answer.

> Dear Marshall Cline,
>
> thank you for all the great work you have done for the C++ community in
>   general and the C++ FAQ in particular.  I was excited to see that it now
>   got integrated with the ISO C++ website together with FAQs from other
>   highly respected people in the C++ community.  Unfortunately, this means
>   that a lot of URLs that pointed to your old FAQ are now broken.  We have
>   recently noticed this problem on Stack Overflow and are now thinking
>   about editing old posts to point to the new location, maybe in a
>   (semi-)automated fashion.  However, this task would be a lot simpler if
>   we had a mapping from old-URL to new-URL at least where this is
>   applicable.  (Even a partial mapping or a general translation heuristic
>   would be much better than nothing.)  Therefore, I wanted to kindly ask
>   if you have some sort of URL-mapping at hand that we could use.  If the
>   content transfer from `parashift.com` to `isocpp.org` was done using some
>   automated script, that would be very helpful, too.  I will be happy to
>   communicate any information you mail me back to the Stack Overflow
>   community.  If you prefer to post it yourself, here is the related
>   discussion:
>
> [Anyone working on updating the broken links related to C++ FAQ?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286672/1392132)
>
> Thank you for your support.
>
> Kind Regards
>
> Moritz Klammler

## Update #1

I got this answer very quickly.

> Thanks. It will take a few days to fix (the problem was the old URL
>   schema which I failed to consider) so in the interim I may revert the
>   parashift site. That's the fastest path to victory. Then I will do it
>   right, and provide you with the mapping as a side benefit.
>
> M

I think this is the ideal solution for all of us (and probably many more on the internet).  My suggestion would be that we refrain from editing old posts then until we hear from him again and get an URL mapping.

In the meantime, it would be great if somebody with greater authority on Stack Overflow could comment whether it would be a good idea to mass-edit old posts with some scripting magic.  I have seen that in July last year, [a similar case was dealt with in an ad hoc manner by the SE team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237110).  Could this be happening again?  Do we have a standard policy on such issues by now?

## Update #2

Thanks to Marshall Cline updating the `parashift.com` website to redirect to the new C++ Super-FAQ, the issue has become a lot less pressing.  If that site is to stay online, I don't see any need to edit the links in old posts any more and recommend against doing so.

For what it's worth, I have generated a mapping and – as requested in [this (unfortunately closed) post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286852/1392132) – verified that the redirections are accurate.  The results can be found [here](http://klammler.eu/data/computer-science/misc/c++faq/index.html).  Most redirections could be verified and for those where verificatin failed, it was probably due to re-wording of the titles.

Comment: Seems that http://parashift.com is down for days now.