# Automatic reputations and badges for prominent people on a subject?

Tags: feature-request

In reference to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286672/anyone-working-on-updating-the-broken-links-related-to-c-faq) question, I engaged in an email conversation with [Marshall Cline](https://www.linkedin.com/in/marshallcline) who is a recognized expert in C++. He mentioned that he is not able to respond due to low reputations on SE. I think there should be a way to award honorary reputations and badges to people recognized as an expert in their field if community supports it. Either the experts themselves may ask for it which can then be put up for voting in the community or others can propose. This may also encourage experts to visit SE more often.

**Update 1**

I see that community is a bit miffed off on this idea. I think we need to be more logical. These experts may not have time from their other endeavors. [Marshall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4601094/marshall-cline) has steadfastly maintained C++ FAQ since 1991 and even now when we pointed out the problem of redirection, He immediately took action to bring back old site quickly till redirection is fixed. There are at least 2500 references to C++ FAQ maintained by him. I think its a bit unfair to expect him to engage everywhere. I proposed community poll to ensure that recognized community leaders only get this privilege not some introvert genius who has not shown any inclination towards community work. Below are Marshal's word from mail

> Unfortunately I don't have enough reputations to respond directly to the thread. Let me know if there's a way I can short circuit that process, or if not please post my earlier action to revert the site temporarily while I fix the links.

It shows that he is willing to contribute once in a while when it concerns things needing authoritative voices, but not on continuous basis.

Comment: Somehow I imagine the hoops one would have to jump through to get this award would be harder than just providing the one quality answer it would take for someone like that to get all the rep they needed to do whatever they wanted.

Comment: I like your proposal. I think to prove themselves, they should post enough answers to get 5 upvotes on answers, then they should be allowed to comment. At least 12,5 upvotes on answers should give them the right to downvote... I think you get where I'm going with that

Comment: Its not *that* hard for an [expert in a field](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/267299/40980) to get sufficient reputation to comment by answering questions they are familiar with.

Comment: @MichaelT They may not have time from their other endeavors. Marshall has steadfastly maintained C++ FAQ since 1991 and even now when we pointed out the problem of redirection, He immediately took action to bring back old site quickly till redirection is fixed. There are at least 2500 references to C++ FAQ maintained by him. I think its a bit unfair to expect him to engage everywhere.

Comment: @user2876962 Completely agree that it's unfair to expect him to engage anywhere, including here. Since he's obviously chosen not to do it over the last 6 years why should SO try to trick him into it by dropping some rep on him?

Comment: @ivarni Because at least in this case, he wanted to do something and could not do. Same may have been the case earlier also which we do not know. Adding answers on SE is not his priority, but getting answers from him would be a value addition for us. Its as simple as that. He is bigger than most of us in C++ world.

Answer (score 24):

If you want to gain reputation *on the site*, you have to participate *on the site*.  That's all there is to it.

If you're not participating on the site, there's no sense in awarding you any privileges or special decorations, since you're not actively participating.

One may contribute wonderful things to the overall programming ecosystem, and that's *wonderful* - don't let me take anything away from that.  But, the point isn't what they've done in the ecosystem, it's what they've contributed **here** that earns them the reputation.

If they're expert enough and inclined to, they can participate and gain reputation *very* quickly.

Comment: They may not have time from their other endeavors. Marshall has steadfastly maintained C++ FAQ since 1991 and even now when we pointed out the problem of redirection, He immediately took action to bring back old site quickly till redirection is fixed. There are at least 2500 references to C++ FAQ maintained by him. I think its a bit unfair to expect him to engage everywhere.

Comment: I don't see why that's unfair.  They make the decision to engage where they choose to.  If they don't engage on Stack Overflow, there's just no reason to  roll out the red carpet for 'em.

Comment: Stack exchange was launched in 2009. Marshall is helping people since 1991. I think that should matter. I am not asking about red carpet, but just enough privileges to enable them to answer, comment and suggest edit in their chosen areas. Perhaps a new badge like "Community SME" or "External SME" or "Honorary mention" can be created. Many other forums have such ways to recognize SMEs whose answers are considered authoritative anywhere they chose to contribute.

Comment: @user2876962 [Brian Goetz](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3553087/brian-goetz) managed to get _some_ reputation while contributing to Java 8 release (helping people since at least [2006](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0321349601))

Comment: @user2876962 it would take Marshall TWO ANSWERS to get to that level. How involved will he be if he can't even produce two answers now?

Answer (score 5):

Reputation is a measure of how much someone has *contributed to this site*. It is an imperfect measure, for sure. For instance, the person who receives a 100 bounty has not contributed 10 times more than the person who receives one upvote on an answer. However, whatever weaknesses the reputation system has, let's not weaken it further by opening the door to "honorary reputation", which is 100% disconnected from past contributions to the site.

As Makoto [said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286820/1906307), it should be relatively easy for an expert to gain reputation quickly on the site.

> This may also encourage experts to visit SE more often.

It is desirable to encourage experts to visit SE sites, but there's a limit to the accommodations that should be made.